# Which language is recommended for developing front end UI (a desktop app) if my back end is written in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, frontend, desktop-application

I have developed a machine learning code in python and I am going to make a nice and modern (not boring classic GUI) UI for my code. What language is recommended to be learnt to develop a front end desktop UI for this kind of code?

My final software supposed to be a standalone desktop software. The front end should do too much chart plotting and map display. Any recommendation?

Comment: QT or PYQT, ( based on C++ ) is the best One ...

Comment: QT may be the best but tkinter can still display plots using tk.Canvas and matplotlib, if done well with classes for buttons, frames etc it can look modern...ish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://electron.atom.io/

all you need to learn is JavaScript, HTML, and CSS

Have a look at the app section too, if you can find apps that resemble your use case.

https://electron.atom.io/apps/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, particularly #4 in the section "Some questions are still off-topic". Questions requesting software or library recommendations are opinion-centric; their answers tend to be subject to debate rather than authoritative, and to become outdated over time. (See also "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, specifying that questions which are outside site rules should be closed rather than answered).